# Require greater than zero if other field is zero in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two number text fields:

```
<input type="number" name="amount_1">
<input type="number" name="amount_2">
```

I need to validate them where at least one of them has a value of at least 1.

I currently have this on my validation:

```
'amount_1' => 'required_unless:amount_2,0',
'amount_2' => 'required_unless:amount_1,0',
```

With the code above, i do not see error message if any of the two field has a value of 1, which is correct. But I do not have error message if both of them have 0 value.

What I need is to have the other textbox to have a value of at least 1 if the other has a value of 0.

If both have a value of at least 1 it is fine also.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules):

Assuming it's a one-off for your application, it's probably easiest to use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount_1' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
        if ($value + $request->input('amount_2') <= 0) {
            $fail('Amount 1 or Amount 2 must be more than 0');
        }
    },
]);
```

Comment: Looking back at this answer, for people looking to copy-paste this code in the future there's a caveat: my little bit of shorthand adding the numbers together causes it not to work with negative numbers.

Comment: Or at least it causes it not to work 100% of the time if your code allows negatives.